# spark process tracking with 'groupByKey'

Tags: apache-spark

I would like to get some log about my spark process. I assume that some code with 'groupByKey' spend time a lot, but no way to check out. 
Any way to check how this 'groupByKey' function flows in my app?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to monitor the flow the best solution is the Spark WEB UI : https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-apache-spark/content/spark-webui.html

Comment: You can use log4j instead. You can trace your code by putting logs wherever your want inside your code. There are many guides regarding log4j in apache spark outhere!

Comment: I can add log print inside my function, but cannot do in spark method like 'groupByKey'. Since It works parallel, I cannot figure out which object and key were working on groupByKey method.